# st terminal: only change cursor's shape when move over text

Tags: cursor, suckless-terminal

Currently cursor always active and visible in `st` that even go over text or not, cursor's shape always like `|`, I'd to change to `|` only when go over text to ready to select, otherwise keep its normal pointer shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in current `st`.  The mouse cursor shape is set by the following line in [config.def.h](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/config.def.h.html#l140) (and therefore `config.h`):

```
/*
 * Default colour and shape of the mouse cursor
 */
static unsigned int mouseshape = XC_xterm;
```

...and never altered anywhere else in the code.

If you modified the above line in `config.h` (using another value from the X11 header file `cursorfont.h`: [possible values, with example appearance](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/)), you would get the new cursor shape all of the time.  To have it change dynamically, based on the contents of the terminal, you'd have to write the feature yourself -- and given the goals of the suckless project, it is unlikely that such a feature would ever appear in unpatched `st`.

Comment: how to change size of `mouseshape`?

Comment: @TuyenPham Please ask in a new question, and include more details about exactly what you want.